# Copy pasting repeated values in a column of a large excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck on a problem and would love some help.

Here is what I'm working with now:

[image]

What I'd like is for column B,C, & D to copy in the blank rows below it until it reaches a new client like so:

[image]

Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how many rows does your excel have ?

Comment: It varies, but right now around 500.

Comment: sorry, and how many unique companies ?

Comment: Around one hundred, however, that changes all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do it on a weekly basis and I'd rather not have to do it manually each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Non VBA solution:**

Select entire range with your data. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and select *Special...*

[image]

Choose *Blanks* and press *OK*

[image]

You would get result as in image below. *With selected cells* type `=` and press <kbd>↑</kbd> key. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Now if you want you can copy result and make *PasteSpecial-->Paste Values*

---

**VBA solution:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, ar As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("A2:D20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        rng.Calculate
        For Each ar In rng.Areas
            ar.Value = ar.Value
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Simoco. Any idea how this would be completed using a macro? The reason I ask is because the list of companies will constantly be changing.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm I tried that and it copies cells B, C & D from the first company throughout the entire spreadsheet. It does not switch companies.

Comment: @simoco - btw, is this VB .NET ? I have used excel only as a text editor.

Comment: I had the same results except "#N/A" showed up in many of the rows.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, it is VBA.